# DynamoDBMapper unconvert attribute error when converting Dynamo JSON to POJO (SAME POJO which i persisted in DYNAMO)

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

I Have a Java object which i persist in dynamo DB . Java object contains MAP, LIST, STRING , INT, OBJECTS etc. Values are getting saved in dynamodb using `@DynamoDBDocument` , `@DynamoDBAttribute` etc , but when i try to fetch a value it shows up an error

> "2018-06-14 16:15:38.957 ERROR 93104 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
>   InvoiceModel[recurringInvoiceDetail]; could not unconvert attribute]
>   with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null"
>
> InvoiceModel is my POJO and recurringInvoiceDetail is a class member
>   which is an object.

Does anyone knows how i can fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After facing this issue and trying to solve it for 3 days. Finally came across this article , it worked .

My mistake was :

Initial:

```
public void set_period(String period) {
this.period = period;
```

}

Changed it to :

```
public void setPeriod(String period) {
this.period = period;
```

}